# Ошибка при билде проекта Android

Tags: android, gradle

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
```

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Вылетает такая ошибка когда пытаюсь запустить приложение.
Но дело в том, что когда просто делаю билд проекта(нажимаю на молоток), то все билдится успешно без всяких ошибок.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При запуске где-то JSON парсите некорректно, скорее всего.

Comment: а как его парсить правильно? как найти ошибку?

Comment: Ваш код хочет получить JsonArray из строки, но строка не имеет json-массива в корне, возможно она вообще пустая. Выведите её содержимое в лог перед парсингом - если не пустая, то ошибка в парсинге, иначе в получении самой строки.

Comment: Нуу. Вообщем бэкапы на каждые 500 строк кода решают!)))

Comment: @woesss не путайте ТС - проблема не с кодом, а с `build.gradle`, подается одиночная строка вместо массива - это ошибка Groovy интерпретатора

Comment: Покажите свой `build.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

Пробуем добавить в

> build.gradle

в блок `defaultConfig` 
строку `multiDexEnabled = true`
и в `dependencies`
строку `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'`

Comment: это какой град, проекта или приложения?

Comment: не робит. ошибки. щас добавлю в вопрос

Comment: есть варианты исправления?

Comment: ау вы тут?? не помогает. что делать? гугл пуст

Comment: По всей видимости в приложении есть запросы к сети, нужно их смотреть, возможно дело в Асинтаск, или в разборе получаемой информации... дебаг версия имеет склонность упускать ряд ошибок для удобства разработки, пробуйте обернуть все подозрительные блоки в исключения и посмотреть в логи где именно проблема.